# Basic Electrostatics Problem Modified

Tags: electrostatics

I was going through lecture notes of a class(this is not a homework question), and I have made a problem I'm myself confused at:

Two parallel infinite conducting planes lying in the xy-plane are separated by a distance $d$. Each plane is uniformly charged with equal but opposite surface charge densities. Find the electric field everywhere in space.

Now, if the planes were non-conducting, it was pretty trivial. But I want to know what happens if these are replaced by conducting planes. Does Polarization takes place? How do we solve it then and what are the changes that can be noticed?

Comment: Capacitor like situation maybe !

Comment: Thanks, got it! Please close this topic now.

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it if you feel like it can help people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***CASE1: - BOTH GROUNDED :*** No plate should have a charge as a result there would be no electric field. 
***CASE2: ONE CHARGED OTHER GROUNDED:*** now whatever charge you give to one plate opposite charge induces to the other plate and the same charge goes to ground so so we have two plates with exactly same charge density (say $\sigma$) but of opposite charges . So the electric field is 2$\times$$\sigma/2\epsilon_0\hat{i}$. 
***CASE3 BOTH ARE GIVEN CHARGES AND ARE ISOLATED:*** You will find by demanding that field at the centre of plates 0 . You will find charge distribution like $(Q_i+Q_2/2)$,$(Q_1-Q_2)/2$,$(Q_2-Q_1)/2$,$Q_1+Q_2/2$ if you go to the sides of plates from left to right. And electric  field would be $(Q_1-Q_2)/2A\epsilon_0\hat{i}$.